# Images overlapping rounded border in carousel component (React, Tailwind)

Tags: reactjs, image, tailwind-css, overflow, vite

I'm working on an *Airbnb* clone project using React, Tailwind CSS, and Vite.

I have a `Carousel.jsx` component responsible for displaying images within a rounded container. The problem is that the images are overlapping the `rounded-xl` border applied to the container, and I'm looking for a solution to fix this issue.

**Here's a live demo:**

[image]

[image]

**Simplified Components:**

`StayPreview.jsx`

```
import { TbStarFilled } from 'react-icons/tb'
import StayImages from './StayImages'

const StayPreview = ({ stay }) => {
  return (
    <article className="group cursor-pointer text-sm">
      <StayImages stay={stay} />
      {/* more stay info... */}
    </article>
  )
}

export default StayPreview
```

`StayImages.jsx`

```
import Carousel from '../layout/Carousel'

const StayImages = ({ stay }) => {
  const paths = stay.imgUrls.map((path) => {
    return new URL('../../assets/images/' + path, import.meta.url).href
  })

  return (
    <Carousel>
      {paths.map((path) => (
        <img
          key={path}
          className="mb-2 aspect-square object-cover"
          src={path}
          alt=""
        />
      ))}
    </Carousel>
  )
}

export default StayImages
```

`Carousel.jsx`

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { TbChevronLeft, TbChevronRight } from 'react-icons/tb'

const Carousel = ({children: slides}) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)

  const prev = () => {
    setCurrent((prevCurrent) =>
      prevCurrent === 0 ? slides.length - 1 : prevCurrent - 1,
    )
  }

  const next = () => {
    setCurrent((prevCurrent) =>
      prevCurrent === slides.length - 1 ? 0 : prevCurrent + 1,
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="relative overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
      <div
        className="flex rounded-xl transition-transform duration-500 ease-out"
        style={{ transform: `translateX(-${current * 100}%)` }}
      >
        {slides}
      </div>
      <div className="absolute inset-0 flex items-center justify-between p-4 opacity-0 transition-opacity group-hover:opacity-100">
        <button
          className="cursor-pointer rounded-full bg-white p-2 opacity-90"
          style={{ opacity: current === 0 ? 0 : 100 }}
          disabled={current === 0}
          onClick={prev}
        >
          <TbChevronLeft />
        </button>

        <button
          className="cursor-pointer rounded-full bg-white p-2 opacity-90"
          style={{ opacity: current === slides.length - 1 ? 0 : 100 }}
          disabled={current === slides.length - 1}
          onClick={next}
        >
          <TbChevronRight />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="absolute bottom-4 left-0 right-0">
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-2 opacity-0 transition-opacity group-hover:opacity-100">
          {slides.map((_, i) => (
            <div
              key={i}
              className={`h-1 w-1 rounded-full bg-white transition-all ${
                current === i ? 'p-1' : 'bg-opacity-50'
              }`}
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Carousel
```

I tried using `overflow-hidden` on various places and while it does show rounded corners at the top side of the div the bottom side stays flat.

As you can see in the provided GIF only the top side is rounded while the bottom one isn't, I want the bottom side to be rounded as well.